# I get error when trying set value to html control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do next:

In Page_Load event:

```
string linkPatches = "PageProcessor.aspx?Page=Patches.aspx&system=" + Request.QueryString["system"];
```

In html:

```
<li><a href="<% =linkPatches %>" style="color:White;">Патчи</a></li>
```

And I get next error:

```
CS0103: The name 'linkPatches' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `linkPatches` is local to the scope of the `Page_Load` event.

You would have to declare this at class level for it to work:

```
public class Your_Page_Name_Here : Page {
    /* public or */ protected string linkPatches;

    public void Page_Load(/*etc*/) {
        linkPatches = "PageProcessor.aspx?Page=Patches.aspx&system=" + Request.QueryString["system"];
    }
}
```

This means it is now available to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to make the variable public/protected, like Simon showed, or you can use an asp control:

Code front:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="_linkPatches" runat="server">Патчи</asp:HyperLink>
```

Code behind:

```
_linkPatches.NavigateUrl = "PageProcessor.aspx?Page=Patches.aspx&system=" + Request.QueryString["system"];
```

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thx. I +1 yours as well because it is still a good concept to know.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev what's wrong with protected? why it should be public.

Comment: @krshekhar Sorry that's not what I meant when I only mentioned "public" in my post. There is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a control with that name in the page, and that it is included in the .designer file. If not, then add it or remove it as needed.

The designer sometimes gets out of sync with the page's markup. Alternatively, right-click on the page that's causing the error and select 'Convert to Web Application' to force a sync.